# How to store data in angularjs application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: Folder Stucture]Hi I am developing my first Angularjs application. I want to save data in Angularjs application for later use(I have used localstorage in jquery before). 
For example, I will make ajax call and i will get some data, Lets say below example,

```
  $http.post('http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/VerifyUser', $stateParams.pageList).then(function (response) {
                alert(response.data);
```

another example, After succesfull login i will get some ID in response and i want to preserve this data all over the application. This ID i may use in all subsequent ajax calls. 
I will get some data in response and i want to make use that data in other controllers as well. Is there any way i can do this? any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store it in factory like below,

After your Ajax call

```
$http.post('http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/VerifyUser', $stateParams.pageList).then(function (response) {

                alert(response.data)
SomeFactory.setData(response.data);
};
```

**SomeFactory**

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.myApp')
    .factory('SomeFactory', SomeFactory);

  SomeFactory.$inject = [];

  function SomeFactory() {
    var someData;

    var factory = {
      setData: setData,
      getData: getData
    };



    function setData(data) {
      someData = data;
    }

    function getData() {
      return someData;
    }

    return factory;
  }
})();
```

**In your Controllers**

inject your factory to your controller and then getdata

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.login')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

  LoginController.$inject = ['SomeFactory'];

  function LoginController(SomeFactory) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.someVariable = SomeFactory.getData();
   console.log(vm.someVariable);  // logs your data

}
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. So i can place Factory i main folder right? I have updated my folder structure. Under Registration folder there is a controller called Registrationcontroller.js. I will get my data to preserve. So i should place my factory inside Registration folder or outside?

Comment: yea you can anywhere in your app under some module, and use whichever controller you want to use , name.factory.js

Comment: How can i inject Factory in required controller? Lets say below is my controller angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('OTPVerification', ['$scope', '$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', 'cfg', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, $state, cfg, $stateParams)

Comment: Thank you. In this line SomeFactory.setData(response.data); I am getting error SomeFactory is not defined.So should i inject SomeFactory in that controller also?

Comment: Please Inject it wherever you want to use, make sure that you have injected your module in your main app.module

Answer (score 1):

Sharing data between controllers can be achieved with the following options :

- **[`Factory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)**
- [Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Then you can inject the service across the controllers and use the data whenever you need.

```
app.service('myService', function($http) {
  this.getJSON = function() {
    $http.post('http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/VerifyUser', $stateParams.pageList).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };
});
```

**In Controller:**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {

  myService.getJSON().then(function(data) {
    $scope.myData = data;
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```

**[`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/hTqOjt?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you. where should i create this service? Lets say i will have data in ajax success call.

Comment: you could create inside the same app, look at the demo for better understanding

Comment: Ok.  $http.post('http://192.168.0.213:1234/api/VerifyUser', $stateParams.pageList).then(function (response) {
                    //Here i will get data so this is the place where i should create service?
            },

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole check this demo https://plnkr.co/edit/s9buAmULiIrmPNAxcQkL?p=info

Answer (score 0):

Use Service to store the data and get the data in another controller later on.

When you inject a Service, it's the same service in every controller - so you can access the properties and methods in that service all over.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Example:

```
.service('YourService', function(){
var YourService = {};
YourService.yourvar = '';
return YourService;
})

.controller('controller1', function($scope, YourService){
YourService.yourvar = 'blah';
})

.controller('controller2', function($scope, YourService){
$scope.currentYourVar = YourService.yourvar;
})
```